# Design Table Html

Tags: html, html-table

I am used to work with backend but now I have to draw this table in HTML.

[image]

Because the rows 5 to 9 just have 6 `<td>` the outcome table is not equal to this one because the last column of the 5 row ends in the 6 column of the first row for example, how can i achive this design? 
With colspan the design will not be equal to this?
Should I use in the rows from 5 to 9 a table inside one each `<td>`?

Comment: You can add main table and then where your column no change add new table and place those column in new table, as i can see your design will need 4 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options)

- Include all cells in one table and use colspan in order to align the way you want
- Use 3 separate tables and then use either the width attribute or css to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no relationship between the rows of columns of the three blocks of table cells so:

*Use three separate tables*

You can use CSS to adjust the margins on the tables to remove the space between them.

---

Cramming this into a single table would simply require judicious use of [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#Attributes), but that doesn't appear to be a good fit for the data here.